# How to do feature selection and reduction on a LIBSVM file in Spark using Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, chi-squared

I have a couple of LIBSVM files with which I have to implement clustering in spark using python. The file has **space** as the delimiter and the first column represents the type [ 1 or -1] and the rest all are the features which are in the format [1:2.566]. There are a lot of columns like this and I would like to perform a feature selection over this [preferably implement the ChiSquareTest model] and then use PCA or SVD to perform a feature reduction process. But, I could not find a decent tutorial for python in spark to implement these processes.

I found a [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/mllib-statistics.html) online that had a sample script to implement Chisqtest in python. I used the same logic to implement the model and I could not get it done. Under the Hypothesis testing division in that link, the code parallelizes the RDD[LabeledPoint] before passing to the ChiSqTest model. I tried the same logic in different manner and I got different errors.

```
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "PATH/FILENAME.txt")
label = data.map(lambda x: x.label)
features = data.map(lambda x: x.features)
obs = sc.parallelize(LabeledPoint(label,features))
```

This gave me an error stating **TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number**

Then, I normalized the data using Normalizer() and did the same thing and got the same error. So, I wrote a function that returns a labeledpoint

```
def parsepoint(line):
    values = [float(x) for x in line.split(' ')]
    return sc.parallelize(LabeledPoint(values[0],values[1:]))
parsedData = data.map(lambda x: parsepoint(x))
obs = sc.parallelize(parsedData)
```

This gave me an error stating **Pipeline RDD is not iterable**. I tried several other methods and everything ended up in an error. Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong? And, for the feature reduction process using PCA or SVD, I could not find a sample script in python. Any inputs for that would be very helpful for me.

Stack Trace:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8d0164c0957d> in <module>()
  10 sct = SparkContext()
  11 data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sct, "PATH")
  ---> 12 print data.take(1)
  13 #label = data.map(lambda x: x.label)
  14 #features = data.map(lambda x: x.features)

  SPARK_HOME\rdd.pyc in take(self, num)
  1263 
  1264 p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry,   totalParts))
 -> 1265 res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p, True)
  1266 
  1267 items += res

  SPARK_HOME\context.pyc in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
   879         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
   880         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(),   mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions,
   --> 881 allowLocal)
   882         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
   883 
      SPARK\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   536 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   537 return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
   --> 538 self.target_id, self.name)
   539 
   540  for temp_arg in temp_args:
    SPARK\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
   298 raise Py4JJavaError(
   299 'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
   --> 300  format(target_id, '.', name), value)
   301   else:
   302   raise Py4JError(

  Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling       z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
  : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task   0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0   (TID 2, localhost): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket      write error
   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
   at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
   at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
   at    org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$wr       ite$1(PythonRDD.scala:413)
   at   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:425)
   at  org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:425)
   at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
   at   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:425)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRD D.scala:248)
   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)

  Driver stacktrace:
   at   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$ $failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
  at  org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler .scala:1257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
  at   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAG Scheduler.scala:730)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala :1411)
 at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Answer (score 3):

`MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile` returns `RDD[LabeledPoint]` so you can pass an output directly to the `Statistics.chiSqTest`. Using example data:

```
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, 'data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt')
chiSqResults = Statistics.chiSqTest(data)

print chiSqResults[-1]
```

Comment: I tried this now. It is not working. CODE: sc = SparkContext() **endofline**
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "FILEPATH") **endofline** fitresult = Statistics.chiSqTest(data) **endofline**  *Getting a big error:* Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Comment: Could you provide more details? What version of Spark do you use? What is going on when you execute `data.take(1)`? Can you run the code on an example input as above?

Comment: I am using Spark 1.4. I am executing the scripts using Ipython. And, when I print the data using data.take(1) I am getting the same P4JJavaError. I used to get the proper output for the rdd.take() function. But, lately, I just couldn't see the output for that function. Don't know what mistake I am doing. And, when I run the script on a sample data, I am getting the output

Comment: Are you sure that an input file is well formed? How did you obtain it? Have you tried to load it outside the Spark? For example with [scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/#datasets-in-svmlight-libsvm-format).

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the contents of my input file. I loaded the file using scikit library and it is getting loaded properly

Comment: I don't know what I am missing here. The spark library seems to get the data, but it does not print the content of the created rdd. Am fairly new to this and not really sure what to do at this point

Comment: Could you provide a full stacktrace as an edit to the question?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the stack trace? Why can't I print and see what's there in the rdd? If I do the data.take() in pyspark terminal, I can see the values inside my rdd. But, the chisqtest does not work in the terminal too

Comment: Looks like a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6660 and it should be already fixed. Have you tried to update your Spark installation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82514/discussion-between-srinath-and-zero323).

Comment: I newly installed Spark 1.4 and integrated it with Ipython before working on the scripts. I am not really sure what exactly I should be looking for from that link. I am fairly new to Spark

Answer (score 0):

Try this for you parsing function. The code after prints the features for the first label and the first label itself. Hopefully this helps!

```
    def parsepoint(line):
        values = line.split(" ")
        return LabeledPoint(values[0], values[1:])

    parsedData = map(parsepoint, data.take(1))
    firstFeatures = parsedData[0].features
    firstLabel = parsedData[0].label
    print firstFeatures
    print firstLabel
```